# Initialize member in print() from another function

Tags: c++

Not sure where I am at the moment, trying to figure it out. I need to initialize the members in print() const as it is giving me random gibberish. No matter what I try to do, it does not seem to work. Not sure what to even do. Can anyone give me a hand?

*edit: Added in the rest of the code. Forgot it when I submitted the first time.

Student.cpp

```
#include "student.h"


//implement the required 3 functions here


Student::Student(const char initId[], double gpa)
{
    // initialize a newly created student object with the passed in value



}

bool Student::isLessThanByID(const Student& aStudent) const
{
//  compare the current student object with the passed in one by id.
if (strcmp(id, aStudent.id) > 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}


}

bool Student::isLessThanByGpa(const Student& aStudent) const
{
// compare the current student object with the passed in one by gpa
if (gpa < aStudent.gpa)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}

}

void Student::print() const
{
cout << id << '\t' << gpa << endl;
}
```

student.h

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
Student(const char initId[], double gpa);
bool isLessThanByID(const Student& aStudent) const;
bool isLessThanByGpa(const Student& aStudent) const;
void print()const;
private:
const static int MAX_CHAR = 100;
char    id[MAX_CHAR];
double  gpa;
};
#endif
```

app.cpp

```
#include "student.h"

int main()
{
Student s1("G10", 3.9);
Student s2("G20", 3.5);

s1.print();
s2.print();

if(s1.isLessThanByID(s2))
{
    cout << "about right!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "uhmm ..." << endl;
}
if(!s1.isLessThanByGpa(s2))
{
    cout << "about right!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "uhmm ..." << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `initialize a newly created student object with the passed in value`

Comment: If you have non-static member variables in a class, and don't initialize them, their value will be *indeterminate* and using them (except for initializing them) will lead to *undefined behavior*. I suggest you search for and read about *constructor initializer lists*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in that code that sets the values of `Student::id` and `Student::gpa`.  Your constructor has parameters `initId` and `gpa`; you should copy those into your object.  Based on the declaration of `Student` that you provided, something this should be appropriate:

```
Student::Student(const char initId[], double gpa) : gpa(gpa)
{
    strncpy(id, initId, Student::MAX_CHAR-1);
    id[Student::MAX_CHAR-1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: The strcpy worked (however I have to use strcpy_s) for the id, and initId. However it doesn't work for the gpa. gpa is set as double in Student and in student.h under public. When trying to use, it gives me a -9.2.5596e+061 instead of the values needed in my app.cpp. (The 3.9 and the 3.5)

Comment: What error do you get?  How is Student::gpa declared?

Comment: It is declared under my Student::Student(const char initId[], double gpa) and in my student.h
    class Student
    {
    public:
 Student(const char initId[], double gpa);
 bool isLessThanByID(const Student& aStudent) const;
 bool isLessThanByGpa(const Student& aStudent) const;
 void print()const;
     private:
 const static int MAX_CHAR = 100;
 char  id[MAX_CHAR];
 double gpa;
    };

Is this a memory leak or something else ? (Sorry still learning.) For the value it gives me is a - 9.25596e+061 instead of what I am needing(the 3.9 and the 3.5)

Comment: I've pasted everything back into the original question.

Comment: That worked. Can you briefly explain what the difference was? Thank you.

Comment: I was originally assuming that your class declared `id` as a pointer (or smart pointer), so I needed to allocate space for it before copying into it.  However, it's actually a fixed-sized array, which means that I don't need to allocate anything, and instead, I need to copy the input into it in such as way as to ensure that I don't overflow the array.  `std::strncpy` copies at most `n` characters into the destination, but doesn't ensure that the string is null-terminated if that limit is reached.  That can be worked around by copying one fewer character and setting the last character to null.